# Is it a better practice to define Interface members as Classes or their Interface equivalent?

Tags: c#, .net

In an interface definition, is it better to declare a member of a type of the desired Class or Interface equivalent? For example, let's say we have an interface called `IFoo` that is implemented by the class `Foo`. If we are declaring another interface `IBar`, and we need a representation of the *Foo thing in `IBar` which is better?

```
interface IBar { 
    IFoo member { get; set; }  // interface
}
```

or ...

```
interface IBar { 
    Foo member { get; set; }   // class
}
```

There seems to be equally valid arguments for both camps. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Interface gives you better flexibility in the future.

Comment: The two examples are not equivalent, and so there is not one that is better than the other. It depends on the situation and what the interface actually means, and even for a given situation opinions may vary.

Answer (score 1):

Using an interface makes it easier to swap out the initial implementation for a new one - without having to update references since they deal with the abstraction offered by the interface.
It can also help you out with unit testing since you can easily mock based on the interface.

A common example where your code is more flexible if using an interface is IList.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces not only provide more flexibility, It also allows you to build better abstractions.

It will also force you to think of things like - If the class implements multiple interfaces, then you have to know what abstraction (Interface) is most suitable, as part of this other interface definition..